# C++ copy construct rvalue reference question

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm learning the rvalue reference concept in c++.

When testing the following code, I found the "fun" was called despite it not using fun(abc &&) to accept the temporary object(prvalue).

```
class abc
{
};
void fun(abc &)
{
    cout << 1111111 << endl;
}
void main()
{
    fun(abc());
}
```

output: 1111111

If this is allowed due to [temporary materialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization)

Why does the following code fail to compile?

```
void fun(int &)
{
    cout << 1111111 << endl;
}
void main()
{
    fun(5);
}
```

Output: Compiler error!

many thanks

Comment: No, the first code sample won't compile either. It's essentially the same error as the second example.

Comment: That shouldn't compile. If it does, I recommend adding the compiler and version number to the question. Someone might recognize what you've run into and be able to point you at a bug report or similar.

Comment: MSVC has allowed this sort of thing by default for a long time, although it's forbidden by the language. If you're using MSVC, be sure to try the `/permissive-` compiler flag to get better standards compliance for this and other differences.

Comment: @aschepler The flag fixed it! Thank you very much for the spot-on answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why both fail to compile is that [temporaries cannot be bound to non-const references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600/501250).

In the first case, the expression `abc()` constructs a temporary `abc` object.  Trying to pass it to `fun()` tries to bind the temporary to a non-const reference; this is disallowed.

The second case is effectively the same thing: the compiler tries to use `5` to construct an `int` temporary, but then fails to bind it to the non-const reference.

```
int const & a = 5; // allowed
int & b = 5;       // disallowed
```

This was an intentional design decision, intended to prevent what would otherwise be very easy mistakes to make.  Let's pretend this rule doesn't exist:

```
void add_one(double & i) {
    i += 1;
}

void something() {
    int x = 5;
    add_one(x);
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Wait... why is `x` 5 instead of 6!?  Because `x` was used to construct a `double` temporary, which bound to the reference argument.  `add_one()` added 1 to the temporary.  Then the temporary is destroyed when control returns to `something()` and the value of `x` was never changed.

But, since temporaries cannot bind to non-const references, the `add_one(x)` line will instead fail to compile.  This saves the programmer from having to figure out that an invisible temporary was implicitly created and destroyed on that one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
void fun(int &)
{
    cout << 1111111 << endl;
}
void main()
{
    fun(5);
}
```

doesnt compile because you cannot pass a reference to a literal to a function that expects a reference to a modifiable variable. Although you dont change it, you might

this works

```
void fun(const int &)
{
    cout << 1111111 << endl;
}
void main()
{
    fun(5);
}
```

Comment: `void main()` shouldn't compile either